# Sunspot fielded queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Let's say I have a model defined as follows (title and description are string and text fields, respectively):

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Skipped

  searchable do
    text :title,
    text :description
  end
end
```

I want to be able to use search queries like "title:foo description:bar", which assumed to retrieve only those Entities which fields meet the search criteria, i.e. Entities which title contains "foo" and/or description contains "bar". Exact syntax doesn't matter.

I tried to type such query in the search field of my demo application, but obviously it didn't return any results :-)

So, does Sunspot query parser support fielded queries (don't sure if the term is correct)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a feature that Solr's edismax query parser should support. However Sunspot currently defaults to the older dismax query parser.

To enable edismax in your searches, try this line in your `search` block:

```
adjust_solr_params { |p| p[:defType] = 'edismax' }
```

(That's off the top of my head; let me know if I missed the syntax.)

Comment: This answer worked for me except that I had to use "title_text(term)" instead of "title(term)".  Is there any way around that?

Comment: Hey Don, Sunspot's `searchable` DSL is all about mapping your model's columns over to a naming scheme for Lucene fields. Its `text :title` is simply generating a field named `title_text`. Reading Sunspot's schema.xml should be pretty educational on that point.

Comment: I found that I needed to use `:defType` instead of `'defType'`.